# Run different database types in different environments in dotnet core 2

Tags: entity-framework, sqlite, asp.net-core, entity-framework-6, .net-core

I want to run a SQLite database in development and a SQLServer Express database in production.

We are using code first with database migrations.

How do I inject a different dbcontext in each environment?

How do I run migrations against a specific database.  E.g.  In development I'll want to run migrations against the SQLite database.

Comment: First, how do you inject your dbcontext? I'm assuming you use some sort of DI container. You can use the IHostingEnvironment and inject the appropriate dbContext accordingly. To run migrations you need to point to a project and run it. The "magic" is which connection string the migration will use. You can use the same interface and get the correct one at runtime. This are just ideas.. not implemented this myself but I guess it's a start.

Comment: Or even better: You can have multiple appsettings that targets your environments. So: one appsettings.Development.json and appsettings.Production.json. Each of them will have the respective connection string. Then you just configure your dbContext with the connectionstring from the appsettings, which you'll always have.

Comment: @jpgrassi That's what we do currently.  But I think I need a different method  to add a sqlite db vs a sqlserver.  Currently we run `services.AddDbContext<OurDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(this.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DBConnection")));`   But to use a sqlite db I think you need to call `options.UseSqlite`.

Comment: Just use the IHostingEnvironment Interface and add the Sqllite when env is development.

Comment: @jpgrassi Ok.  I think I am going down a similar path to what you described.  Will code it up and post back what worked.  Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So I guess I found a nice way for you to do that. You can use the [ConfigureDevelopmentServices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments) startup convention to add your SQLSite DbContext. So, just as some basic example you would have:

```
// Production "like" ConfigureServices
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Use Sql Server
    services.AddDbContext<SchoolContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ProductionConnection")));
}

// Development ConfigureServices
public void ConfigureDevelopmentServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Use SQL Lite
    services.AddDbContext<SchoolContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DevelopmentConnection")));
}
```

You can even go further and add a ConfigureStagingServices if you happen to have another different context for staging only. To avoid copy and pasting of common services, you could have a private method that register the common services and have the separate ones only with specific stuff.

Now for the migrations, I never tested this but, my best guess is if you have the correct dbContext and the correct connection string, the migrations will work fine. You just point to the EF project and run it.

Comment: Great.  Didn't know about the `Configure<Environment>Services()` convention.  Slick.  Migrations unfortunately get more complicated because Sqlite doesn't support all the migrations that sql server does.  But not sure there is any easy answer for that one.  Going ahead and marking as the accepted answer.

Comment: Glad it helped. Yeah.. migrations are always a pain.. so glad to be using a noSQl db now :).

Answer (score 1):

For the official MS response, see [Use SQLite for development, SQL Server for production](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/model?tabs=visual-studio-code&view=aspnetcore-5.0#use-sqlite-for-development-sql-server-for-production)